# How to load content from third party site, and from where?

Tags: ajax, auto-update

I am developing a jobsite. I like to load career advice from anywhere (like blog, other sites, rss, etc.), and it should be updated automatically if there is a change in source.

How can I achieve this, and from where I can get the required content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform an Ajax request on a time interval, if there are changes, then update the content on the page

Ajax with jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From where i can get those information?

Comment: Is it require web service for this?

Comment: the ajax connection's url is whereever the source of the data is. that may be simply a file on your own server... or to some API / RSS feed on some other server.